# Has any player on the Edmonton Oilers roster (16-17 season) played a postseason game as an Oiler before this season?

Tags: trivia, ice-hockey, nhl, stanley-cup, postseason

The [Edmonton Oilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonton_Oilers) advanced the NHL playoffs this season (2016-17) for [the first time since the 05-06 season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Edmonton_Oilers_seasons) when they reached the [Stanley Cup Final](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_Stanley_Cup_Finals). So given the 11 year hiatus, I'm wondering if there are any current Oilers who also played for them the last time they made the playoffs?

Or equivalently, are there any players on the Oilers roster who have played in the playoffs for the Oilers before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Eberle has the longest tenure with the Oilers with 7 seasons played, but as you mentioned before, it has been an eleven year hiatus.

With an eleven year drought, the only eligible members on the roster who could be in the league are as follows (I've included their age at the last time Edmonton got into the playoffs along with when they joined the NHL):

- Matt Hendricks, 24, entered NHL in 08-09, COL
- Jonas Gustavson, 21, 09-10, TOR
- Mark Letestu, 20,  09-10, PIT
- David Desharnais, 19, 09-10, MTL
- Benoit Pouliot, 19, 06-07, MIN
- Andrej Sekera, 19, 06-07, BUF
- Mark Fayne, 18, 10-11, NJD
- Kris Russell, 18, 07-08, CBJ
- Cam Talbot, 18, 13-14, NYR

Comment: Probably correct, but a player could have left the Oilers and returned.